# How to import single function from packages with the same name

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

What should I do about this? It seems python is calling the first function.

```
from numpy.random import multivariate_normal
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
```

Comment: `from numpy.random import multivariate_normal as name`

Answer (score 0):

The usual convention is:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.multivariate_normal
```

Then there won't be such collisions.

Comment: It seems this imports the whole package, therefore not-so efficient?

Comment: That's not how it works really.  There is no loss of efficiency by doing it this way.  Try it.